# CloudFormation complaining about changeSet [InvalidChangeBatch]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

When I'm trying to deploy my code, I’m getting this error:

```
module.rest_api.aws_route53_record.xxx: 
[ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to create resource record set [name=‘MYNAME’, type=‘MYTYPE’] but it already exists]
status code: 400, request id: XXXXXXXXXX
```

When I inspect the stack, it seems empty, so I’m not able to delete the stack? Could anyone help with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are checking in the correct region and account.

Comment: I doubled checked my account and region, they both look correct to me, in my ~/.aws/config and credentials file, as Im using aws configure to manage them.

Comment: I mean when you write "When I inspect the stack,", how do you inspect it? In aws console?

Comment: I checked it both on the console and the cli, console shows no stacks at all, on cli, I see an empty array

Comment: Did you go to route53 console and checked there?

Comment: I just checked that, and found my domain name under the records list, that might be it. I deleted it now, and I'm running my terraform file now, lets give it a 10mins or so!! Thanks a lot for your quick responses, this is truly amazing !! Thanks.

Comment: This is to confirm that it's indeed working! I can't believe my eyes, now my server is working. Thanks for you expertise and kindness !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **existing record set** in Route53. The **solution** was to delete the record in Route53 console and use CloudFormation to re-create it.